# Is "I can't remember the name to it" a valid sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is this a correct sentence. If yes, does this convey the same meaning as "i cant remember its name"

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi eefar, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: I agree with the comment from @Chappo & will flag it accordingly. But **No**, “I can't remember the name **to** it” is NOT a valid sentence: “I can't remember the name **of** it.” would be a valid sentence.  Also, "i cant remember its name" is NOT a valid sentence because it is incorrectly punctuated, capitalised and  spelt: it should be "**I can't** remember its name." (with a full stop at the end!).

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "valid". Strictly speaking, "I can't remember the name to it", isn't what you would expect from a native English speaker, although the meaning is quite clear. We might say "I can't remember the name of it", which would be synonymous with "I can't remember its name". 
Note that there is no apostrophe required in the possessive pronoun"its".